# Proof for complex limits.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have to prove the following statement: If $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} f(z)=a$, where $h$ is a function defined in every $f(z)$ and $\lim\limits_{w\to a}h(w)=c$, then $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}h(f(z))=c$.

So far, I have this proof, keep in mind these are all complex functions:

Let $\varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that if $|w-a|<\delta$ then $|h(w)-c|<\varepsilon$, and $\exists \delta_1 >0$ such that if $|z-z_0|<\delta_1$ then $|f(z)-a|<\delta$. Therefore $|h(f(z))-h(a)|<\varepsilon$ when $|z-z_0|<\delta$.

From this I want to conclude that $|h(f(z))-c|<\varepsilon$ when $|z-z_0|<\delta$, which gives me the existence of the limit. But in order for this to happen I have to consider three cases:

1. $|h(f(z))-h(a)| = |h(f(z))-c|$
2. $|h(f(z))-h(a)| > |h(f(z))-c|$
3. $|h(f(z))-h(a)| < |h(f(z))-c|$

With the first two cases the proof is immediate, but I'm stuck on the third one and don't know how to justify it. Any hints?

Comment: Depending on how your limits are defined this is not necessarily true. One definition of the limit is that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0 $ such that if $0<|w-a| < \delta$ then $|h(w)-c| < \epsilon$. This says nothing about $h(a)$. However, we could have $f(z) = a$ for all $z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true.  Take for example
$$z_0=0$$
and
$$f(z)=|z|\sin\Bigl(\frac1{|z|}\Bigl)$$
and
$$h(z)=\cases{1&if $z=0$\cr 2&if $z\ne0$\cr}\ .$$
Then
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=0\ ,\quad
  \lim_{w\to0}h(w)=2\ .$$
But in any neighbourhood of $0$ there are points
$$z=\frac1{n\pi}\quad\Rightarrow\quad h(f(z))=h(0)=1$$
and
$$z\ne\frac1{n\pi}\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(z)\ne0\quad\Rightarrow\quad h(f(z))=2\ .$$
So $\lim_{z\to z_0}h(f(z))$ does not exist.

If $h$ is continuous at $a$ it will work.